# jquery mobile web application developement( need help)

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, jquery-mobile

Can any one please tell me how to send data to web service using jquery and receive data from web service?
If we are using web service should we need to use url to get records?

```
$j.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "testing.json",
        dataType :'json',
        contentType:'application/json; charset =utf-8',
        success:function(data)
        {
        $j.each(data, function(index,element){
            $j('#json').append("<li class='ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-c ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom ui-li-last'>"+element+"</li>");
         });
        }
    })
});
```

I am developing web application using jQuery mobile.

Answer (score 0):

> Can any one please tell me how to send data to web service using jquery

Put it in a `data` property on the object you pass as the first argument to `ajax()`.

How you format the data will depend on the particular web service.

Your existing code claims that it will be JSON so the data you pass to `data` should be a string representation of a JSON Text.

You will need to change the type to `POST` in order to do this though. The `content-type` request header describes the request body and you don't get one of those with a `GET` request.

(If the web service does not expect to receive JSON data then you will need to change the code to represent whatever it *does* expect).

> and receive data from web service?

Read it from the first argument to the callback function you pass to the `success` function.

If it is in a known data format (XML, HTML or JSON), then jQuery should automatically parse it. Note that you have `dataType: 'json'` which will override whatever the server says it is sending back and try to parse it as JSON data regardless.

> If we are using web service should we need to use url to get records?

Yes. URLs are how web server end points are identified.

Answer (score 0):

a liitle example to get data from a web service using jquery ajax call

```
function GetData() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Members.asmx/GetMemberDetails",//your webservice call
        data: "{'MemberNumber': '" + $("#txt_id").val() + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnGetMemberSuccess,
        error: OnGetMemberError
    });
}

function OnGetMemberSuccess(data, status) {
    //jQuery code will go here...
}

function OnGetMemberError(request, status, error) {
    //jQuery code will go here...

 }
```

Example: [Introduction to using jQuery with Web Services](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/349598/Introduction-to-using-jQuery-with-Web-Services)